# How to display rating bar in android?

Tags: android, rating

I am successful to parse JSON and display in listview.
In list view I displayed name, town and rating, which valued are already stored in database.
I want to display the rating bar instead of rating number there. 
Also it should not support any user interaction, I mean I want to display rating bar only for information.
How can i do this ??
Help !!

```
        // Getting Array of Root
        root = json.getJSONArray(TAG_ROOT);

        // looping through All root
        for (int i = 0; i < root.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject c = root.getJSONObject(i);

            // Storing each json item in variable

            String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
            String town = c.getString(TAG_TOWN);
            String totalRating = c.getString(TAG_RATING);

            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();



                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value

                map.put(TAG_NAME, "Name: " + name);
                map.put(TAG_TOWN, "Town: " + town);
                map.put(TAG_RATING, "Rating: " + totalRating);

                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                myList.add(map);

        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    /**
     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
     * */
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, myList,
            R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_NAME, TAG_TOWN,
                    TAG_RATING }, new int[] { R.id.name, R.id.address,
                    R.id.rating });

    setListAdapter(adapter);
```

**list_item.xml**

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="vertical" >

   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="2dip"
    android:paddingTop="6dip"
    android:textColor="#006fa8"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />


   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/address"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="2dip"
    android:textColor="#acacac" >
   </TextView>

   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/rating"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="2dip"
    android:textColor="#acacac" >
 </TextView>  

 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hello Check below code

```
<RatingBar 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:isIndicator="true"
    android:numStars="5"
    android:stepSize="1"
    android:rating="5"
    android:id="@+id/pop_ratingbar"
    style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
/>

RatingBar ratingBar = (RatingBar) findviewbyid(R.id.pop_ratingbar);
ratingBar.setRating(4.0f);
```

Comment: I wrote the following code   `........ String totalRating = c.getString(TAG_RATING);   RatingBar ratingBar = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.pop_ratingbar);  
    float totalRatingValue=Float.parseFloat(totalRating);
    ratingBar.setRating(totalRatingValue);
 

            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put(TAG_NAME, "Name: " + name);
....................

` but gives the force close error.

Comment: @captainpirate -- Can you show your logcat as I don't think there is a error while setting rating value if your TAG_RATING is convertible to float..

Comment: RatingBar is displayed to each list item but when i add     `ratingBar.setRating(totalRatingValue); ` Then my programs gives force close error.

Comment: logcat: 
`04-04 16:48:42.041: D/AndroidRuntime(1971): Shutting down VM
04-04 16:48:42.041: W/dalvikvm(1971): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
04-04 16:48:42.120: D/dalvikvm(1971): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 6241 objects / 236960 bytes in 75ms
04-04 16:48:42.140: E/AndroidRuntime(1971): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-04 16:48:42.140: E/AndroidRuntime(1971): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity...........................................`

Comment: @captainpirate please check totalRating values once again may be it is giving error in converting values try to debug code also it will be good if you paste your code in pastebin so that I can check it.
As per your code I don't see any problem.

Comment: I find out that its not working only inside this for loop.When i tested it in another project just giving the value manually,its working. I think we have to find new approach for this condition.

Comment: @captainpirate -- have you checked response values?? Are they all able to convert in float?? Check in same loop by giving hard-coded value. If you show this class may be I will help you

Comment: yaha, solved it dude, made my own adapter which extends simpleadapter and set the rating, its working now. Thanx for the help !!

Answer (score 6):

Create an object of RatingBar and assign the relevant ratings with float value.

```
RatingBar ratingBar = null;
ratingBar.setRating(4.0f); // put the rating number you are receiving through json here.
```

Here you are getting in String, so you have to type cast to float.

```
     String totalRating = c.getString(TAG_RATING);
     Float.parseFloat(totalRating);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Rating bar is there in android [see this](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/RatingBar1.html) [this](http://androidorigin.blogspot.in/2010/10/android-ratingbar-demo-program.html) and [this](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-rating-bar-example/)